# Filling list nan values

Tags: python, pandas

How to fill nan values with 0's in a list. I can do it for dataframes but don't know how to do it for lists?

```
listname=listname.fillna(0)
```

This isn't working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert to a pandas series and back to a list

```
pd.Series(listname).fillna(0).tolist()
```

Consider the list `listname`

```
listname = [1, np.nan, 2, None, 3]
```

Then

```
pd.Series(listname, dtype=object).fillna(0).tolist()

[1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use list comprehension and check with [math.isnan](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan):

```
import math
listname = [0 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in listname]
```

But that would not work with non float types, if you have strings, other numeric types etc.. in your list then you can use `str(x) != 'nan`'

```
listname = [0 if str(x)=='nan' else x for x in listname]
```